# Date sorting and reverse

Tags: javascript

I have 2 dates: '11/28/2018' and '09/25/2019' and using these dates i have the following date range from 25th of endday.

```
[09/25/2019 , 08/25/2019, 07/25/2019....12/25/2018]
```

I want the date in reverse order instead.

`[12/25/2018......7/25/2019, 8/25/2019, 09/25/2019]`

I have the following code.

```js
function createLedger(stDate, etDate) {

  if (stDate && etDate) {
    var endOfLeaseDate = moment(etDate, "MM/DD/YYYY");
    var startOfLeaseDate = moment(stDate, "MM/DD/YYYY");
    dateRange(startOfLeaseDate, endOfLeaseDate);
  }
}

function dateRange(stDate, etDate) {
  var dates = [];

  var now = etDate.clone();
  var day = etDate.date();

  while(now.isAfter(stDate)) {
                        var month = now.clone().endOf("month");
                        if (now.date() < day && day <= month.date()) {
                            now.date(day);
                        }
                        dates.push(now.format("MM/DD/YYYY"));
                        //dates._reverse();
                        now = now.clone().subtract({"months": 1});
                    }
                    console.log(dates);
                }

function RunLedgerAndPV() {
  var stDate = "11/26/2018";
  var etDate = "09/25/2019";
  createLedger(stDate, etDate);
}
RunLedgerAndPV();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

I tried using dates.reverse(); and dates.sort(); however, it's not returning the desired output.

Output using .sort()

`["01/25/2019", "02/25/2019", "03/25/2019", "04/25/2019", "05/25/2019", "06/25/2019", "07/25/2019", "08/25/2019", "09/25/2019", "12/25/2018"]`

Output using .reverse();

`["12/25/2018", "02/25/2019", "04/25/2019", "06/25/2019", "08/25/2019", "09/25/2019", "07/25/2019", "05/25/2019", "03/25/2019", "01/25/2019"]`

Also, tried the sort function but it didn't work either.

```
yourArray.sort(function(a, b) { return new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date) })
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What is the output you are getting?

Comment: `etDate.clone()` is throwing an error for me.

Comment: Sorting (and reversing O.o) the array for each `.push()` is a waste of cpu cycles.

Comment: @LloydFrancis Just updated the question with my output. Thank you.

Comment: @ace23 can you tell me a bit about what you are trying to do? Do you already have the array in an order and you want it in reverse? Or are you creating the array?

Comment: @LloydFrancis I have the array. I just updated the code again. I want it in ascending order basically. You can see it's in descending right now.

Comment: @ace23 so you want it in the exact reverse order of what you get when you use `.sort()`? I am trying to understand your exact requirement. In that case, you can combine both to do `.sort().reverse()`.

Comment: But this does that: `console.log(dates.reverse());` ... or how does it not?

Comment: @LGSon `reverse()` method basically just reverses the entire array in order and gives it to you. If you need it in any particular order, you might have to use it along with `sort()` function because `reverse()` in itself has nothing to do with sorting

Comment: @LloydFrancis Well, I know that, just wanted to make a point that the existing array sample will work with that alone, so OP has what they need, just need to understand how it works.

Comment: Sorry, got you. :-)

Comment: @LloydFrancisYes. The exact opposite order. I have also mentioned the desired output in my question. And doing that didn't work. You can see that when i use .sort(), it's placing 12/25/2018 at the very end. It should've been in the first element in the array followed by whatever is in sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
function datecomp( d1, d2 )
        {
            var a1 = d1.split("/");
            var a2 = d2.split("/");
            a1 = a1[2] + a1[0] + a1[1];
            a2 = a2[2] + a2[0] + a2[1];
            return (parseInt(a1) - parseInt(a2));
        }

        dates.sort(datecomp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running the loop from enddate to startdate in reverse:

```
     var stDate = "12/31/2018";
     var etDate = "12/31/2019";

     var Endnow = stDate.clone();
     var Endday = etDate.date();
            while(Endnow.isBefore(etDate)) {
                    var month = Endnow.clone().endOf("month");
                    if (Endnow.date() < Endday && Endday <= month.date()) {
                        Endnow.date(Endday);
                    }
                    dates.push(Endnow.format("MM/DD/YYYY"));
                    // dates.sort(); <= not required
                    // dates.reverse(); <= not required
                    Endnow = Endnow.clone().add({"months": 1});
                }
```

Comment: which line? just check if isBefore() and add() functions are there in js library or you may need to write custom isBefore() and add() functions

Comment: Yes. It is in the library. Tried copying the code into the snippet and run it. It crashes everything.